# Convert Node.js datetime string to delphi datetime with timezone

Tags: node.js, delphi, converters

I´m receiving a date time from a node.js server like this

> "Wed Mar 31 2021 23:20:04 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time)"

And i need to convert to TDateTime and back to this format.

I´m looking for procedures or functions in delphi to do this, but not luck at all.

Comment: This is an RFC822 modified by RFC1123 5.2.14 (4 digits year) date time format. There are in the internet many Delphi source code to convert that format to TDateTime and back. Google is your friend. You should fin it in Internet Component Suite (ICS) and in Indy because that is used in EMail.

Comment: @fpiette AFAIK the RFC's mandate the use of GMT (optionally denoted UTC), and always include a comma after the day so a strict parser would not parse the format provided.

Comment: @RobLambden Maybe, I don't know. If this is the case, the OP could slightly modify the source code he will find for the RFC I mentioned to make it more tolerant.

Comment: In my way, timestamp(1980-Now secend) as the Middleware, to syn time